# Convert array of arrays to object of arrays, using ramda

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

Given an array of either 2d or 3d data. How can one create a function that converts the data to object of arrays, where the inner index maps to x, y or z depending on if the index is 0, 1 or 2 respectively. For example:

```js
// 2d
const inputData2d = [
    [-1, 4],
    [3, 6],
    [9, -8],
]

const outputData2d = {
    x: [-1, 3, 9],
    y: [4, 6, -8],
}

// 3d
const inputData3d = [
    [-1, 4, 5],
    [3, 6, 2],
    [9, -8, 5],
]

const outputData3d = {
    x: [-1, 3, 9],
    y: [4, 6, -8],
    z: [5, 2, 5],
}
```

The function should also be able to handle both 2d and 3d data, behaving as expected. I've explored using `pipe` and `assoc` but no luck as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ramda you can [Transpose](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) the array of arrays, and then use [R.zipObj](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj) to combine it with the keys. R.zipObj truncates the zipped arrays to the shorter of the two, so you can supply `['x', 'y', 'z']`, and it would be truncated to `['x', 'y']` for the 2d data.

```js
const { pipe, transpose, zipObj } = R

const fn = pipe(transpose, zipObj(['x', 'y', 'z']))

const inputData2d = [[-1,4],[3,6],[9,-8]]
const inputData3d = [[-1,4,5],[3,6,2],[9,-8,5]]

console.log(fn(inputData2d))
console.log(fn(inputData3d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And the same idea works with lodash, although it's more verbose. You'll need to use [`_.unzip()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#unzip) instead of R.transpose, and pick keys with values using [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#pickBy):

```js
const { flow, unzip, zipObject, pickBy } = _

const fn = flow(
  unzip, 
  arr => zipObject(['x', 'y', 'z'], arr),
  obj => pickBy(obj)
)

const inputData2d = [[-1,4],[3,6],[9,-8]]
const inputData3d = [[-1,4,5],[3,6,2],[9,-8,5]]

console.log(fn(inputData2d))
console.log(fn(inputData3d))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

And you can remove some of the verboseness with Lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, unzip, zipObject, pickBy, identity } = _

const fn = flow(
  unzip, 
  zipObject(['x', 'y', 'z']),
  pickBy(identity)
)

const inputData2d = [[-1,4],[3,6],[9,-8]]
const inputData3d = [[-1,4,5],[3,6,2],[9,-8,5]]

console.log(fn(inputData2d))
console.log(fn(inputData3d))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: I'll race you to the lodash solution :)

Answer (score 2):

First, [transpose](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) the input and then [zip it into an object](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipObj).

```js
const matrixToTransposedObject = R.compose(
    R.zipObj(["x", "y", "z"]),
    R.transpose
);

const inputData2d = [
    [-1, 4],
    [3, 6],
    [9, -8],
];

const outputData2d = matrixToTransposedObject(inputData2d);

console.log(outputData2d);

const inputData3d = [
    [-1, 4, 5],
    [3, 6, 2],
    [9, -8, 5],
];

const outputData3d = matrixToTransposedObject(inputData3d);

console.log(outputData3d);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ramda@0.27.1/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```